# Bootstrap horizontal 100% width dropdown-submenu in 100% width horizontal dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Good day everyone,

I am trying to make 100% width horizontal dropdown menu coming from "Menu2". In "Menu2"->"SubMenu2" Iam trying to make 100% width horizontal dropdown SubSubMenu. Any ideas for the best solution?

Many thanks for all help.

```css
body {
  min-height: 2000px;
  padding-top: 70px;
}


.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-submenu{position:relative;}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu{top:0;left:100%;margin-top:-6px;margin-left:-1px;-webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu{display:block;}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after{display:block;content:" ";float:right;width:0;height:0;border-color:transparent;border-style:solid;border-width:5px 0 5px 5px;border-left-color:#cccccc;margin-top:5px;margin-right:-10px;}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after{border-left-color:#ffffff;}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left{float:none;}.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu{left:-100%;margin-left:10px;-webkit-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;}


@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
.dropdown > li{
  display: inline-block;
    float:center;
    
 }
.open> ul {
    display: inline-flex !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Test</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#about">Menu1</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu2</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu1</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">SubMenu2</a>
                   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">SubSubMenu1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SubSubMenu2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SubSubMenu3</a></li>
                   </ul>
                  </li>          
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu3</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Menu3</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="../navbar/">ENG</a></li>
              <li><a href="../navbar/">LT</a></li>
              </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
      

     

    <div class="container">

      <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1></h1>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p>
          <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Button</a>
        </p>
      </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is to disable dropdown's `position: relative` and place it on a parent that has the desired width:

```css
#navbar {
  position: relative;
}
#navbar .dropdown.has-container {
  position: static;
}
#navbar .dropdown.has-container .dropdown-menu.container {
  margin: 0 -15px;
}
```

```html
<!-- ... -->
  <li class="dropdown has-container">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" 
        data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" 
        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu2</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu container">
        <li><a href="#">SubMenu1</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">SubMenu2</a>
<!-- ... -->
```

Proof of concept:
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/jyLk8L80/2/).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9foe71a9/ if you zoom Prieview window enough, you will see that  <li> tags with "ENG" and "LT" has dropped to the second row.

Comment: Much obliged @Andrei , that is a huge step forward. Now I am stuck on trying to center align "SubMenu" also, maybe you know how is possible to make center aligned "SubSubMenu" in one line, same as "SubMenu"

Comment: Use `display: flex;  justify-content: center;` on `#navbar .dropdown.has-container .dropdown-menu.container` to center the contents.

Comment: Many thanks for reply @Andrei , contents are centered, but now "Submenu" contents are always visible https://jsfiddle.net/cnmbemzb/1/

Comment: :) My bad. change `#navbar .dropdown.has-container .dropdown-menu.container` to  `#navbar .dropdown.has-container.open .dropdown-menu.container`. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/cnmbemzb/2/)

Comment: Bravo @Andrei , that worked out. Now I am trying to make "SubSubMenu" to look same as "SubSubMenu", horizontal dropdown with centrally aligned content. I was trying to use :

Comment: I was trying to use the same solution with containers you provided, but after this "SubSubMenu" contents are always visible https://jsfiddle.net/jyLk8L80/1/ . May you say where I am missing the point?

Comment: Please try to use [so] in order to understand principles. Everyone volunteers here. If you have trouble understanding a particular CSS property, post a specific question about it. However, it's highly unlikely that someone will build complex functionality step by step based on subsequent requests. This is not a coding service. I'm trying to help you learn. Make sure your questions are formulated so future readers benefit from it. That's why you should never make additional requests to the original one.

Comment: Well, I get the point @Andrei. After all, many thanks for your help, have a nice day :)

Comment: You nailed it @Andrei, success! Will it be possible to update your Answer with [This](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/jyLk8L80/2/) solution?

Comment: I've done it, but I don't think it's that important. In the above comments I managed to guide you closer to a solution for your particular case. But the answer is supposed to explain the principle so future visitors will be able to apply it their cases.